# Object loacaliztion and detection using Tensorflow

Tags: localization, tensorflow, detection

Is there any tutorial for Object localization and detection with inception model V3 on Tensorflow?
Thank you.

Comment: have you found anything about that? I'm struggling finding something similat too

Comment: Unfortunately, No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) was released recently.

I highly doubt if you can use your inception model on it. You generated model is for object classification while what you need is object localization.